# How to set visible data labels in each marker using a PhpSpreadSheet Line chart?

Tags: php, excel, label, linechart, phpspreadsheet

My code is very similar to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Chart/33_Chart_create_line.php.
I see the chart and the markers but not the data labels on each marker. See the attached output:
[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Hgy.png)

Thank you very much.
I tried a lot with parameters in DataSeries and DataSeriesValues but nothing. The documentation is a little bit poor also.

PIECE OF CODE

```
public function downloadExcel(Request $request){
        

        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $worksheet->fromArray(
            [
                ['', 2010, 2011, 2012],
                ['Q1', 12, 15, 21],
                ['Q2', 56, 73, 86],
                ['Q3', 52, 61, 69],
                ['Q4', 30, 32, 0],
            ]
        );

        // Set the Labels for each data series we want to plot
        //     Datatype
        //     Cell reference for data
        //     Format Code
        //     Number of datapoints in series
        //     Data values
        //     Data Marker
        $dataSeriesLabels = [
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$B$1', null, 1), // 2010
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$C$1', null, 2), // 2011
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$D$1', null, 3), // 2012
        ];
        // Set the X-Axis Labels
        //     Datatype
        //     Cell reference for data
        //     Format Code
        //     Number of datapoints in series
        //     Data values
        //     Data Marker
        $xAxisTickValues = [
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', null, 4), // Q1 to Q4
        ];
        // Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
        //     Datatype
        //     Cell reference for data
        //     Format Code
        //     Number of datapoints in series
        //     Data values
        //     Data Marker
        $dataSeriesValues = [
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$5', null, 4),
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', null, 4),
            new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$5', null, 4),
        ];
        $dataSeriesValues[2]->setLineWidth(60000);

        // Build the dataseries
        $series = new DataSeries(
            DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART, // plotType
            DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED, // plotGrouping
            range(0, count($dataSeriesValues) - 1), // plotOrder
            $dataSeriesLabels, // plotLabel
            $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
            $dataSeriesValues,        // plotValues
            null, //plotDirection
            false, //smoothLine
            DataSeries::STYLE_MARKER //plotStyle
        );
        /*
        const STYLE_LINEMARKER = 'lineMarker';
        const STYLE_SMOOTHMARKER = 'smoothMarker';
        const STYLE_MARKER = 'marker';
        const STYLE_FILLED = 'filled';*/

        // Set the series in the plot area
        $plotArea = new PlotArea(null, [$series]);
        // Set the chart legend
        $legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_TOPRIGHT, null, false);

        $title = new Title('Test Stacked Line Chart');
        $yAxisLabel = new Title('Y Axis Label');

        // Create the chart
        $chart = new Chart(
            'chart1', // name
            $title, // title
            $legend, // legend
            $plotArea, // plotArea
            true, // plotVisibleOnly
            DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP, // displayBlanksAs
            null, // xAxisLabel
            $yAxisLabel  // yAxisLabel
        );

        // Set the position where the chart should appear in the worksheet
        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('H20');

        // Add the chart to the worksheet
        $worksheet->addChart($chart);
        
        $filename = 'test.xlsx';
        //ob_end_clean();
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        //ob_end_clean();
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        //exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

To show data label on every point, it is possible to create `Layout`, use `setShowVal` method with `true` parameter and pass `Layout` as parameter in `PlotArea` (first parameter, it is `null` in your example).

So the code should be:

```
$layout = new Layout();
$layout->setShowVal(true);

$plotArea = new PlotArea($layout, [$series]);
```